# Test Class for SchedulableClass

Tags: class

How can I write a test class for this scheduler class:

```
global class AccountRevenueSchedulable implements Schedulable 
{
private static final String EVERY_JAN_1 = '0 0 5 1 1 ?'; //every Jan 1 at 5:00am

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Database.executeBatch(new AccountRevBatchable());        
}

global static void scheduleJob(String title, String cronExpression){
    System.schedule(title, cronExpression, new AccountRevenueSchedulable());

}

global static void scheduleJob(){
    scheduleJob('Account Revenue Rollups (Jan 1)', EVERY_JAN_1);
}

}
```

My current test class only covers 66%

```
public static testMethod void test_schedulable(){
  AccountRevenueSchedulable.scheduleJob('Account Revenue Rollups', CRON_EXP);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have specified two constructors for you scheduler. But in test you're using only one of them.
Just create second test, where you can call second construtor:

```
static testMethod void test_schedulable1(){
    AccountRevenueSchedulable.scheduleJob();
}
```

If you open developer console, click tab tests (left bottom), then check class you're interested in from overall code coverage (right bottom). 
You can see lines, which was covered:

[image: test coverage]

Unfortunately sometimes its glitches, so just keep simple rule - execute every line from you class in the first place and then try to cover negative and positive scenarios. Please follow [Add a Test Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm)

Comment: actually, the testmethod as you wrote calls the other (first) constructor so it should replace the existing testmethod